# PF's graphicImage doesn't render

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'am using JSF/PF anf I can't make a graphicImage work. Reviewing the tons of topics published on forums, this PF's graphicImage seems to be so tricky. I am obviously doing somethig wrong, but, as long as I am replicating code that worked for others (see post), it must be something in the environment of the component. I hope to find a solution here, i'm stuck for weeks. Thanks

Here is my original question in PF forum:

I encounter a problem rendering the image. I have followed the code explained and I correctly retrieve the id for image to display in a separate method:

```
public StreamedContent getStreamedImage() {

        StreamedContent streamedImage = null;
                UIViewRoot uiRoot = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot();

        System.out.println(uiRoot.getClientId());

        UIComponent component = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent("itemDataForm:imagesTbl:itemImgComp");
        Map attributes = component.getAttributes();
        Integer image_id = (Integer)attributes.get("item_img_id");

        if(image_id != null && editionItem != null && editionItem.getImages() != null){
            for(ItemImageView img : editionItem.getImages()){
                if(image_id.intValue() == img.getId()){
                    streamedImage = new DefaultStreamedContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(img.getImage()), "image/jpeg");
                }
            }
        }else{
            streamedImage = new DefaultStreamedContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(editionItem.getImages().get(0).getImage()), "image/jpeg");
        }
.......
```

I could't manage to retrieve the  (always null) so I tried with attribute and it works. So, the DefaultStreamContent is loaded, by the image doesn't render at all. My code for xhtml:

```
<p:dataTable id="imagesTbl" var="itemImg" value="#{itemEditionBean.editionItem.images}">
                                        <p:column>
                                            <h:panelGrid columns="1">
                                                <h:outputText value="#{itemImg.id}"/>
                                                <p:graphicImage id="itemImgComp" value="#{itemEditionBean.streamedImage}">
                                                    <f:attribute name="item_img_id" value="#{itemImg.id}"/>
                                                </p:graphicImage>
                                            </h:panelGrid>
                                        </p:column>
                                    </p:dataTable>
```

Exactly the same that the code working in this topic above. PS: I have mt dataTable enclosed within a tab. Maybe a dependency on the enclosing component, or form, or what?

There is a huge amount of code from other related topics that can be viewed in the link below:

http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4163&p=39751

Comment: Please post the original question here.

Answer (score 2):

Based on another page I found on [building dynamic images](http://vineetreynolds.blogspot.com/2011/07/building-dynamic-image-based-carousel.html), `<f:param .../>` should be used to supply a parameter to the `getStreamedImage()` method rather than `<f:attribute .../>`.  Are you using a ConversationScoped backing bean?  I was having the same [problem displaying dynamic images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8067478/primefaces-graphicimage-not-displaying-jpeg-image-supplied-by-backing-bean), but found that there is a [problem using them with ConversationScoped beans](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=16123).  I switched my backing bean to Session scope and now it works fine.